# How can my race combine kinetic weaponry with high explosives?

Tags: science-based

My race use a weapon which has the same dimensions and mass as a kinetic rod. The difference is that it's also a high explosive. It explodes *after* impact, causing the already weak structure to be blown apart. These weapons are to be used in space, so no external oxygen.

**How can they make this more effective than just straight-up kinetic bombardment?**

Comment: My race also uses them more or less. I think this one is one of the most excessive uses so far: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Hamburg_in_World_War_II . They were mainly used out of spite/revenge and to demotivate the civilian population and to a lesser extent to destroy industry or just because they were popular at that time (during the Korea war). For such goals they are more effective than conventional artillery.

Comment: Are these space based weapons, or land based?

Comment: @Innovine question updated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are describing is an [armor piercing shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armor-piercing_shell). Specifically you are describing an APHE (Armor Piercing High Explosive) shell.

APHE refers to a class of projectiles with an armor piercing penetrator and a shock resistant explosive with a delay fuse. These are designed to pierce the armor before detonating.

There is a trade off between kinetic rounds and explosives. The properties that make a good penetrator, hardness, stability and density are not what makes a good explosive. The normal solution is to use different materials for the penetrator and the explosive sections.

Comment: Indeed. It's also how gravity bombs are often used - the GBU-28 is a notable example.

Comment: Also look at the "hittiles" used by the Thales Starstreak MANPAD system -- they're LRP-like projectiles with internal post-impact bursting charges.

Comment: Most of the energy from a naval shell would typically be in the explosives carried.  The kinetic energy was significant, but mostly useful to get the explosives into the right place.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, any chemical based explosive is out of the question. The thing is, high energy kinetic impact will turn the shell (and part of the ship's armor) into plasma : basically an indiscernable soup of nucleons and electrons. I don't think any chemical reaction is possible at this point (since chemical reactions are based on atoms/molecules destroying bonds and forming new ones).

I see two possible solutions :

- Make your explosive not chemical, so... go for nukes.
- Make your kinetic impactor not too fast in order to actually allow some kind of reaction. But I recommend using handwavingly powerful explosive to overcome the greatly reduced damage output of a conventionnal ("not too fast") shell.

In both cases, please note that an explosion in simple contact with the hull of the ship won't make much damage (compared to a purely kinetic impact). Your explosive have to be *inside* the hull to maximize its potential, so go for a penetrating shell before going boom. But once again, the difference between *penetrating* and *vaporizing* ultimately depends on the composition of the armor and the shell.

Comment: What if the shell was made from a *very* strong material, but designed so that is was strong in compression, but any forces pulling it apart (explosions) will cause it to break?

Comment: @Aric Fowler That's a possibility, with a bit of handwavium. I merely stated the requirements, the rest is up to you, and the idea of a very strong shell is as good as another ;). We could go further : maybe the shell contains two separated compounds, and when the shell starts to brutally decelerate in the hull (after a few meters pushing inside like a nail in a piece of bread), the extremely high G-force squish them together and... then things go boom.

Comment: @Keelhaul -- that fits *beautifully* with a gun-type fission warhead even ;)